# Make the search box bigger

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, user-interface

Anybody else feel that the search box is a bit small?  I'd like to see it 1.5x to 2x as big as it currently is.

Reason why is that it won't hold a simple search phrase + a couple tags.

Comment: I wanted to ask this same question. Because in Google we can search and its more comfortable, then this tiny text box. Bigger is mind relax if we find or not find our results.

Comment: [So prescient.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101317/stack-overflow-searchbox-increases-in-width-automatically)  Tag changed to reflect.

Comment: So this is the guy responsible for the extremely annoying auto-expanding search bar? GET HIM!!!

Comment: @NullUserException_: Hey, I didn't say to animate it!

Comment: @won yes you did. *YES YOU DID*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do know that the size of the box does not limit the size of the text inside it, right?

Comment: Do you know ponies nip and kick?

Comment: Yeah its not the size its how you use it!

Comment: Please add the Search box more bigger, left or middle, to have a feel like Google (in google.com it has life, more breath to type a lot)

Answer (score 13):

It's big enough. If it needs anything, it's better results.

Answer (score 5):

I think the search box is the correct size for initiated users and professionals. Any bigger and it would attract attention away from more important areas of the UI and also leave less room for my badge collection.

For new users though it could stand to be bigger/more salient. In fact [I suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/maintaining-superuser-signal-to-noise-for-new-users) making it the landing page for superuser.com for users who are not signed in and got my hat handed to me. So I think its safe to say its staying where it is.

Answer (score 0):

The search bar now expands when clicked on, roughly to 2.5 times its original width.

Comment: Way to "solve" a [non-existent] problem by adding a new one. This is disastrous.

Comment: I find this extremely distracting. My search terms suddenly shoot off miles to the left whenever I want to change them. The search box was already large enough. Is there any way to disable this?