# FR: Make the searchbox wider

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make the search box bigger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/make-the-search-box-bigger)

Seriously, it's only 16-chars (W) long.  What gives?

Comment: Seriously...what gives with your tone?

Comment: Son, you think pixels grow on trees? Who's gonna buy all those extra pixels?

Comment: I can tell this question is photoshopped 'cause the search box needs pixels.

Answer (score 3):

Your facts aren't quite right.  I see way more than 16 characters in the image below.

[image: example]
This image has **not** been photoshoped.

Comment: Not?  Then how did you add the disappointingly-nonfreehand rectangle!

Comment: @Gnome, well I used mspaint.  And, by that standard I suppose it has been 'shoped.