# Stack Overflow Searchbox increases in width automatically

Tags: discussion, search, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make the search box bigger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/make-the-search-box-bigger)

Is this a new feature added to searchbox in stackoverflow websites. When I click on the search box it automatically expands in length hiding my username and other details near it. I have never seen it before. [image]

Comment: SE engine never stops to amaze us :)

Comment: That's definitely changed since the last time I used that search box. (Which was fairly recently ~1week)

Comment: might be I am using it today! kinda of very late I believe!

Comment: Yup, that's new sometime in the last 24 hours. I'm not sure I like it. I rarely have to type more than will fit in the normal size search box, and I hate "features" where the UI moves around. Very disorienting.

Comment: "Do my eyes deceive me?"  No.

Comment: Definitely changed in the last 12 hours

Comment: @Won't, [are you happy now?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/make-the-search-box-bigger)

Comment: @NickDandoulakis: Ah, so many of my [meta-tag:status-declined] questions eventually became completed.

Comment: Ridiculous. In what way a does a question that have asked a doubt about a new feature does relate to a question that has requested a feature earlier. This is not an duplicate. IT could be better if there are some other reasons generated to close this question rather than saying it as an duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/make-the-search-box-bigger

Comment: I find this extremely distracting. My search terms suddenly shoot off miles to the left whenever I want to change them. The search box was already large enough. Is there any way to disable this?