# Make Control-Enter open search results in a new tab/window

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, usability

Apparently the team have got [their hands in the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101387/please-tone-down-or-remove-the-auto-expansion-of-the-search-box) right now anyway, so I'd like to suggest this ultra-minor tweak so that I don't have to control-click on the site logo and download a whole page which I don't even want to read, just so that I can search.

Comment: I'd suggest `Alt`-`Enter` as well, like the search box implemented in Firefox (and perhaps other browsers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neat idea - this will be pushed in a bit.

Comment: Wow, thought-to-implementation in less than an hour!