# Search in new window/new tab

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, search

This situations happens frequently when I am writing an answer. While typing, I remember an old answer that covered some further related aspects. So I would like to find the relevant link. How do I do this?

I cannot enter the top-right searchbox directly for I am editing an answer. Or at least, the currently written answer might get lost (yes, I know it is saved automatically, but will I really find my way back to the link?).

I could open the link [Questions] in a new window or a new tab (I do right-click then select from a menu for that), but then I lose my tag in the search box. Also, I then get a list of 4M+ questions that are entirely unrelated and confuse me.

Every time I am in this situation I feel entirely shackled. Am I missing some obvious point?

What I would like to propose is a tiny link to the right of the searchbox. Then I could right-click there, and get the searchbox (with the principal tag) in a new window. Or maybe not a direct link, but when right-clicking the searchbox I'd get the option to open another window/tab with the search.

((It has been already proposed to have a key bound to this: This is a bit different in that it retains the original tags, and that it uses the same action one uses to open a new window))

This is certainly only of interest to people who write answers that link to other answers, I know, I know that is 0.000something% of all answers... But maybe this might also increase better researched answers.

Comment: That could also help searching for duplicates for voting to close.

Comment: If you use **Opera** you can just bang out Ctrl + Enter to open the search in a new tab

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101422/make-control-enter-open-search-results-in-a-new-tab-window

Comment: @random: I'm Firefox.  But do you think it makes sense to learn a new key for that? In that it remains much hidden to the regular user.

Comment: Ctrl to trigger new tab is how it works for most other sites

Comment: @random: As for your link: I did add the remark above, but quite ironically had exactly the problem again and thus did not search to get the precise link....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on your user name at the top (I press `CTRL` to open a new tab) and your profile view opens. The search box on the top contains your user-id.

Type your search text in the search box. It will only search your posts (because of your user-id being in the search query)!

That way you only need 1 click to search your past posts.

Comment: +1: Surprise! Your suggestion is unintuitive, but it is really almost it: Only the tag is missing. And I cannot claim that looking on my profile is disruptive :-).

Comment: Could it be that the view-counter goes up with this?

Comment: The view counter of your profile? Mine is not.