# The recent search box position change when typing is annoying

Tags: discussion, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeek, the super-mega-expando search box is annoying, part 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101862/eeek-the-super-mega-expando-search-box-is-annoying-part-2)

The recent change of the search box where it suddenly moves to the left to expand is annoying.

1- It happens as soon as I type. I haven't reached the end of the box so why does it need to go through that process!? Why doesn't it figure out how many characters I typed and then go through the expansion only when needed..  like when reaching the right edge of box.

2- There's a lot of empty space to the right of the box. Why not make the box bigger in the first place by expanding into that space?

UI elements which suddenly move away from their location is not normal and I am sure it violates standard UI behavior.