# Let users with sufficient reputation use "problem" in titles

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, title, question-restrictions

This is partly related to: [Using the word “problem” in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles) – however this one here is an actual [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

---

### Problem, Sir?

I am trying to edit [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/204223/there-is-a-problem-with-the-office-database) that contains a specific error message, namely:

> there is a problem with the Office database

Error messages are the first thing people search for on the internet, therefore I feel it is **absolutely necessary** to have the error message in the title of the respective question. It used to have it, and I didn't want to change much on the title apart from adding quotes.

However, I get …

[image]

… and frankly, this does not make sense. I have made almost 3000 edits on Super User now, and I don't believe I can't be trusted to add whatever I deem necessary to the title. From my experience, titles don't get much editin' love anyway, and it shouldn't be made harder to edit them.

Even more so, this "feature" makes it impossible to ever revise an old post **without breaking it**. "Problem" can occur in almost every error message there is. Would you rather have a post with the title …

> Error in Outlook

… than …

> "There was a problem with the connection" error in Outlook

Which one is more meaningful? Of course, this is just an example, and the question I linked to shows other issues like "problems" in the domain of mathematics.

And while I'm sure there are several posts where "problem" really does not make sense in the title, I think there are far more serious title issues that need fixing (which however can't be fixed by a simple blocking filter).

---

### Feature Request

I therefore suggest that users with enough privileges should be able to edits posts freely, regardless of the current restrictions in place.

Given that "problem" in titles is mainly abused by new users, "enough privileges" could mean:

- full edit privileges (2k),
- review privileges (5k) (in case the above is not enough)
- a certain number of edits approved, such as being awarded the [`strunk & white`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) badge

Comment: +1 I wanted to edit a post on SO that had "Problem" in the title, to fix several spelling errors & other snafus, but couldn't save it the revisions because the OP had put "Problem" in the title and I left it there.  I didn't want to change the title - just fix some bugs in the question. I left it as-is, rather than try to pass the test.  So, an ugly question sits around because of a staring match on words in titles.  Why should I make the question conform to pass an obviously inappropriate automatic rule?  An enforced edit is as enlightened as the machine that enforces it.

Comment: +1 This is restriction is one of the worst features ever implemented on SO. It's right up there with the [expanding search bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101862/eeek-the-super-mega-expando-search-box-is-annoying-part-2).

Comment: @NullUserException I know, and while it might be helpful to eliminate some bad titles, it's just so ridiculous when you begin to think about it. I have 23k reputation all around the SE network, I've edited over 3000 posts, and I can't put the word "problem" into my title, even when I try to fix others' posts?

Comment: @Kevin any feedback on *why* this is declined?

Comment: Why don't you guys take the constructive criticism and try to work around these issues.  The community wants it.  Why would you "status-decline" it with no reason.

Comment: I guess it's a way of them saying: Problem?

Comment: Bump for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771/what-is-the-biggest-problemm-with-software-development). Trying to correct the spelling in the title.

Comment: @SamDeHaan I have to say though, the question you linked to is really not a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @slhck Yes, but it's one of the questions old enough that the community has decided to keep it around, so I would like to at least be able to correct the spelling.

Comment: @KevinMontrose♦ Can you explain why this was declined. It's one of the worse aberrations on stack exchange.

Answer (score 41):

**Why not allow *problem* if it's within a quoted statement?**

Examples:

Subject Line: `I am having a problem with app XYZ` *(disallowed, as under current rules)*

Subject Line: `Crashed with "A problem occured in module DEF"?` *(allowed, as it's within quotes)*

I imagine it should be straight-forward to incorporate this as a validation rule. Sure it could be exploited, but people exploiting or misrepresenting through the subject line get downvoted/moderated anyways. This proposed validation would still filter most subject lines according to the original intent, but allow @slhck's subject line through (which I agree is useful when hardcoded error messages are involved).

Overall, this would satisfy @slhck's situation while not separating abilities into two classes of user as @Frédéric and @Kevin brought up.

Comment: I personally don't want _another_ arcane rule to memorize.

Comment: `I am having a "problem" with app XYZ`

Comment: @BenLee Yea but how often do you see a title like that? If someone titles their question that way, they are probably a novice to the Q&A format or english writing, and the rest of their post is likely to have more serious issues than the title requiring community/mod edits/review.

Comment: @BenLee having a "problem" means you have no problem, right? So the question might then be deleted right away ;-)

Comment: @Tomas, touche :).

Answer (score 18):

What we have here is very rudimentary spam filter.  The system has a number of other approaches to spam:

- [rewriting trailing punctuation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115327/1438),
- [bouncing questions that don't meet some nebulous quality criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115307/1438),
- post flagging,
- post editing,
- question closing,
- and, of course, reputation itself.

Some are built into the system and others are ad-hoc solutions that are bolted on over time, develop institutional inertia, and will likely bug people for many years.  (I'll let the reader categorize the above and other approaches I haven't thought of.)

When it comes to ad-hoc solutions, such as filtering on the word "problem", the system slowing devolves into a mass of unintelligible exceptions to the model.  Most programmers have the mental tools to deal with that sort of system, but we are now inflicting it on non-programmers and that seems a mistake.  (I gather this particular tweak is only for Stack Overflow itself, but I'm going to argue that there is a better way.)

A good sign that a solution is ad-hoc is that actual users (not fresh-off-the-street users, but people who have already participated in the site) start finding ways (such as Unicode) to get around the annoying rules.  They start defending questions that end in "!??!!" on the basis of some obscure programming language where this is valid syntax.  They aren't doing it to be annoying or because they legitimately like those sorts of questions or even want to read more of them, but because the rule is (in their opinion) stupid.  Plus it's a basic hacker impulse to find clever ways around system limitations.

Ultimately the whole idea of creating an ad-hoc spam filter has been invalidated for years.  Here's what [Paul Graham](http://www.paulgraham.com/spam.html) says about them:

> If I thought that I could keep up current rates of spam filtering, I would consider this problem solved. But it doesn't mean much to be able to filter out most present-day spam, because spam evolves. Indeed, most antispam techniques so far have been like pesticides that do nothing more than create a new, resistant strain of bugs.

If we are already going to try to automatically filter posts for "quality", why not go all the way and use a Bayesian filter?  Given human votes, reputation, and a massive corpus of posts and edits, there ought to be more than enough information to work with.  And of course there's ten years of prior art.

One additional benefit is that it will be possible to give users a qualitative reason for what's wrong with their question:

> 99.3% of questions that include the word "problem" in their title have a score of -3.
>   Maybe, just maybe, you should rephrase the question.

I'm not sure about implementation details, so this particular behavior might be as bad an idea as the current system.  It would be a sort of self-fulfilling prophesy as people would learn not to use certain words and the only posts that have them would be bad ones.  Perhaps adding reputation in the mix would make the filter more than just banning certain words.  The point is to make the system more objective than just "I've seen a lot of bad questions that have the word "problem" in the title, so we should ban that word."

Comment: Good diagnosis. I don't think anyone disputes that the word is an indicator of crap; the <del>problem</del> issue is that there are legitimate, even _necessary_ uses of the word that are now impossible.

Comment: @Problem That, and the fact that you even lose a good indicator of crappiness when you forbid the word.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this already with some cheating.

Inserting [U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) somewhere in the word "problem" bypasses the filter. That character is invisible, and should be ignored by text processors that understand Unicode.

I applied this technique to [a Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1132847/380318), and Stack Exchange search [can still find it](https://superuser.com/search?q=title%3A%22problem+with+this%22) perfectly fine, [as can Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+internet+explorer+problem+with+this+web+page). I did make sure to include a non-ZWNJ'd version of the error in the body of the question for search engines that don't handle Unicode quite right.

On Windows, you can copy a ZWNJ to your clipboard using the `charmap` utility. Search for "zero width" and U+200C is the second thing found.

I believe this loophole should not be closed. (Better yet, just implement the change asked for in this question.) I don't expect non-effort-expending users will exploit it to write bad titles, and if they do, they were warned. Sometimes, it really makes sense to have an error message in the title verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

> **Update:** In light of your comment, I guess I missed the main point of your question, and I should be more specific about the last
>   paragraph of my original answer.

Truth is, I don't think that allowing trusted (2k+) users to bypass the `problem` filter is the way to go, mainly because:

- Either the filter is useful (not having `problem` in question titles actually *helps* the site), and then I can't see why *my* edits or *yours* or *Jon Skeet's* should be able to bypass that filter,
- Or it isn't, and putting `problem` into titles should be allowed for *everyone*.

I understand we want to discourage low-quality questions, and the aforementioned filter should apply to edits in order to prevent clever users from editing `problem` into their question titles right after posting them. Then again, I don't think 2k+ elitism would serve us there as well as it does on other aspects of the site.

In short, if the `problem` filter indeed causes problems, let's improve it *for everyone* or get rid of it *altogether*. Ignoring the issue while making 2k+ users immune to its effects looks like a fix for the symptom, not the root cause.

> Original answer follows:

Well, to be fair, `There is a problem with the Office database` is an incredibly generic error message.

Your edit aims to give that message more prominence in searches, and that's fine, but are you really sure the question actually represents such a notable manifestation of that message? Or that the answers provided will solve more than, say, 10% of the problems related to that message?

Because if it's not the case, your edit might prove counter-productive in the long run, as it will shadow other, maybe more appropriate questions about the same message in searches (assuming, of course, you don't edit these questions as they come).

Now, regarding the filter, maybe we could allow `problem` in titles when enclosed in double `"` (and maybe single `'`) quote characters? That seems like a natural way to include an error message in the question title (you're using it twice in your question), and it doesn't offer a filter-circumvention path much stronger than `pro-blem` or zero-width spaces IMHO.

Or maybe we can get rid of the `problem` filter altogether, but I'm too young here to know the importance of the issue it was supposed to solve and how efficiently it ended up solving it. So, I can't really advocate that.

Comment: My point is: "There is a problem with the Office database" *is* the actual error message. I don't care if it's generic – that's Microsoft's fault, so to speak. There's not much context to add from the question (maybe Time Machine, maybe permissions), but from what I've experienced, the error message is the main "hook" here. Regarding the filter, I've thought the same (enclosing in quotes), but that still leaves the problems in other domains (like mathematical "problems"), and I'd just get rid of the filter for trusted users.

Comment: Concerning your edits: Yes, you do have a point there. That's why I added the option of allowing it for those who have proven to make good edits (e.g. by getting the `strunk & white` badge). I *do* think **the rule itself a bad measure**. It's crazy they came up with it, because it's really … sneaky in some way. And – as I said in my question – there are a lot of other things to fix in titles. If it were for me, the blocking shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: **However**, *> I can't see why my edits or yours or Jon Skeet's should be able to bypass that filter* – because you are given trust not to abuse "problem" in titles. The filter could still arguably be useful for new users who don't get the gist of the site.

Comment: Also new here.  I suspect there may have been users who entered uninformative titles, like "Problem with C++ compiler warnings" or "Problem with arrays in Java" and so on.  Extending my hypothesis forward in time: in order to nudge people toward more informative titles, someone created a heavy-handed filter.  Now, the pendulum has swung enough that early "problem" questions remain & yet need edits - albeit not in the title (my case - see comment below the OP's question), or the actual term "Problem" needs to be in the title (the OP's question).  (Continued)

Comment: (Continued) Thus, some of us may be satisfied that excluding "Problem" in the title is reasonable for newer users, who should be encouraged to be informative in their titles, and yet more experienced users presumably already see the value of informative titles.  Filtering "Problem" makes them focus on ways to get around the filter, rather than focusing on the site and the questions.

Comment: The [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles) this question is linked to, specifies legitimate uses for the word "problem," and requiring quotes to bypass the filter wouldn't improve matters. So, I think your second suggestion, remove the filter entirely, is the good one.

Answer (score -10):

### Is `problem` really meaningful or necessary in the title?

What I expect from a title is that it clearly tells me what problem the user is experiencing, and *only that*.

I care whether you have BSOD 0xED or 0x124 and their name, but I certainly not care about error messages, descriptions or similar specific details in the title. Looking at your example

> there is a problem with the Office database

*doesn't significantly mean anything*, because it doesn't clearly tell me about the underlying problem.

A title that would literally copy an error message is just *lazyness*, you don't want titles to be like...

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first?

But rather have a guiding title like

> How can I troubleshoot my TDR crash that occurs while watching video streams?

---

### Is `problem` really meaningful or necessary in your example?

Looking at your specific question, I see the following things:

- A restore has happened (with TimeMachine)
- Permission problems are related.
- The database doesn't appear to load.

These details result in better alternatives for a title:

- **How do I fix my Office database after restoring a back-up?**
- **Why does Office report database and permission errors after a restore?**

These are more helpful for people scanning the question list and looking for something to answer.

As for search engine purposes, the question body is indexed too so that's not really an issue...

---

### Are titles containing `problem` meaningless on Super User?

Putting your example aside, in general these titles containing `problem` are meaningless:

- Can you solve my problem with my computer?
- Why does my browser have a problem with visiting Stack Exchange?
- Please help me with my slow computer problem?

Also note that `I have a problem...` is a quite commonly used forum title suffix.

Think of [MLK](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Martin_Luther_King,_Jr.) saying "*I have a dream...*". Then question yourself "*What dream? How can I help?*"

As Jeff Atwood has [shown me once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101935/can-the-ask-question-page-be-changed-to-obtain-better-quality-questions/102150#102150); please **[don't make me read](https://superuser.com/posts/328432/revisions)** unnecessary text. [Thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/145350).

---

### Where there legitimate uses of "Problem" on Super User in the past?

Check out [this search query](https://superuser.com/search?q=title%3Aproblem) and [this search query](https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A13567+title%3Aproblem). How good I am trying to look there, I don't see any legitimate uses of Problem there. Please note that Reputation, even in the 1st query, doesn't matter.

---

### Here is a solution based on your low quality suggestion in the comments:

The proper solution is to add a hidden `hasBeenFiltered` field to the Ask Question page that gets enabled when a filtered word has been tried; which automatically gets the word on the low quality page, that tells on the low quality page what filter triggered. We keep the filter and perhaps add `issue`. That way, we don't have to edit `problem` or `issue` out ourselves in the case of better titles.

This way, it still gets filtered and we get to review them to handle the bad cases.

While [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3aproblem) and [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78949) don't have this filter in place, this filter is a necessity on other SE sites as they don't have programming or mathematical problems. I doubt if Programmers.SE is an exception...

Comment: I disagree with you that having error messages in titles is pure laziness. When people get an error message, the first thing they do is type it in. Your alternative suggestions are good, but the first one needs interpretation (maybe it's not the backup that caused the problem?) and the second one actually contains "problem" again :) — my whole point is: By eliminating problem, you force users to think about a better title, but it's exactly these kinds of users who use "problem", who then fail to come up with a better title and just use something else, like "issue" (ctd …)

Comment: (…) … however, by doing that, you also restrict all legitimate uses, like the "Halting Problem", or any kind of mathematical problem, and there is no way to mention those in a title anymore. I wanted to make the distinction between having established users being able to use whatever they want in a title and restricting new users, which definitely *is* necessary on sites like Stack Overflow.

Comment: @slhck: The question title box is not a search box. Indeed the second contained problem, but errors fits as well. Indeed, words like issue are possible too but are less common. Perhaps the filter warning that comes up needs to be more descriptive, so they don't go for synonyms. "Why does my computer halt?" doesn't contain problem. I doubt if someone will ever have a problem with something like Problem Steps Recorder in Windows. Note that mathematical problems are of an exceptional kind, [hence it's allowed on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78949).

Comment: @slhck: You should check out [this search query](http://superuser.com/search?q=title%3Aproblem) and [this search query](http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A13567+title%3Aproblem). How good I am trying to look there, I don't see any legitimate uses of Problem there. Reputation, even in the 1st query, doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Yes, these are terrible titles. I don't even doubt that, nor have I ever – the point though is, [these](http://superuser.com/search?q=issue) aren't better, and that's the next synonym I'd use if I were lazy and problem wasn't allowed. The list could be continued.

Comment: @slhck: Then we should inspect them and add those to the filter.

Comment: Noooo, not any more filters please. It's the completely wrong approach to such a problem. What I've suggested elsewhere is just putting them into "low quality" automatically, and let others check it. There are so many other bad titles that you can't automatically filter, and by letting people make the mistakes you have a way of actually finding them. If you just remove "issue" and "problem", the titles will be just as bad as before, but you'll have no way to track them.

Comment: Also, "Why does my computer halt" is not what I mean by the ["Halting Problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), c.f. 4600 results on Stack Overflow for it: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=halting+problem

Comment: No, I don't have any statistics on whether it's working fine, because **there is no way to find out**. By eliminating the indicator of bad quality, you make it disappear, but you don't have a proof that it's actually improved anything.

Comment: @slhck: Do you have any statistics on whether the current "problem" filter is not working fine? A case-by-case analysis on the different titles tried by the user could help us come to a conclusion about that, but it's simply not worth spending time into that. Please note that less words in the title automatically contribute to the low quality filter...

Comment: @slhck: **I do have proof, these search queries were full of crap.** Please note that Stack Overflow and Mathematics are not Super User, "programming problems" and "mathematical problems" are exceptional compared to "computer problems". Which don't have their own terms like "halting problem"...

Comment: Please note that this filter is also [not in place on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3aproblem), just like it is [not in place on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78949)... So, we are talking about Super User and other SE sites here.

Comment: See, my whole point is: If I have a query with 5000 really bad problem titles (and I don't doubt that they're bad), then at least you can tell that they're bad. If you restrict people from using it, there are two possibilities: 1) they use a better title, 2) they use another crappy title without the word "problem". Either way, you can never find out what really happened.

Comment: Again, you **did** have proof that those queries were crap. Now, you can't perform this query anymore. How are you ever going to find the crap now?

Comment: @slhck: The proper solution is to add a hidden `hasBeenFiltered` field to the Ask Question page that gets enabled when a filtered word has been tried; which automatically gets the word on the low quality page, that tells on the low quality page what filter triggered. We keep the filter and perhaps add `issue`. That way, we don't have to edit `problem` or `issue` out ourselves in the case of better titles.

Comment: Yes, the latter suggestion would be a way to do that. It's similar in the sense that it needs peer review, but I'd be fine with such a solution.

Comment: @slhck: By the looks of it your original question makes sense in the case of sites were the filter actually isn't in place, I would agree in that case. Now that you have a new idea, I don't see that mentioned in the question and I doubt if they'll check the bottom of my answer after declining the request. So we have two options here that might draw more attention to it: Edit the question to adapt to these new ideas; or, start a new question for a fresh start.

Comment: I'd probably write a new feature request in the next few weeks. The way these requests (although they have 76 upvotes) are shut down makes me think it's better to wait a bit and then try again.

Comment: Good idea, @slhck. Good luck with it. Tell me when you do, you'll get my upvote... :)

Answer (score -62):

We're not open to tweaking validation rules based on reputation, the same quality filters and rules apply to everyone.

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)-ing this one accordingly.

---

Took a look at [Frédéric Hamidi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164403/frederic-hamidi) suggestion, namely to use quotes as a signal that "problem" is in an error message or similar and thus not indicative of a garbage title in those cases.

That is, `Windows Problem!` versus `Getting "problem connecting to server" exception with .NET Socket` tiles; both of which would currently be rejected.

While not a bad suggestion in and of itself, it turns out almost nobody actually tries to format tiles that way.  Historically, < 0.2% of all problem bearing question titles exist between quotes on Stack Overflow (Server Fault < 0.5%, Super User < 0.8%).

Current trends are that < 0.2% of all rejected titles with `problem` in them contain problem between quotes on Stack Overflow.  During the same period, Server Fault has 0 (of the 39 that were rejected for `problem` in the title), and Super User has 2 (of the 30 rejected). Small sample size of Server Fault and Super User, but the Stack Overflow trend is obviously steady.

So this suggestion not being implemented as it would have no effect, and it would complicate the title check pointlessly.

Comment: In which way is this a *quality* filter? I understand that you see a value in these filters for a large number of posts by new users, but you eliminate all legitimate uses of words by doing so. This might not even be based on reputation, as I suggested, but rather based on the abilities to make valuable editing contributions.

Comment: As an alternative, to keep the rules the same for everyone. Instead of preventing posting a question with 'problem' in the title, just show the message warning it might not be considered as a good question.

Comment: @Steven I already proposed automatically flagging such questions as "low quality" in order to have them in the `/review` queue, but they don't want that either, since it's more work for others.

Comment: @slhck: Where is the link so I can upvote that! :)

Comment: @Steven It was [just a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem#comment-286811), but could of course be made into a proper feature request, which could then be `status-declined`.

Comment: So what we need to do now is look for a Unicode replacement of `P`... or  start using things like `Pr0blem`. Great.

Comment: @Pekka U+1D18.  :P

Comment: @Pekka: Próblém :P

Comment: Oh, that will do *great* things for searchability from Google...

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Question bodies are indexed.

Comment: @Tom When searching, what do you look at? A, or B? http://i.imgur.com/BLJqz.png (Funny thing is: You edited the title)

Comment: @slhck: Interesting... Question titles like the one I suggested in my answer might get too specific, which flee away people that have kind of a similar problem but not an exact match. However, it gets [put bold in the message under it](http://i.snag.gy/e9212.jpg). *Yeah, edited with Firebug so the URL is still old and I didn't bother waiting on indexing...*

Comment: @Michael yeah, but if it's the only way to resist this "feature" that nobody except the SO team seems to want....

Comment: This filter is 100% useless: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles/112939#112939

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-the-worst-idea-ever-implemented-on-so

Comment: -1 - The answer seems out of nature with the goal of stackoverflow.  The response is a slap in the face to your users.

Comment: What a joke. What happened to the concept of 'trusted users'?

Comment: This is a community of experts.  Clearly, the experts don't agree with this decision.  Ignoring their opinion is very much against the "openness and community" spirit of SO.

Comment: @Jon - quality filtering is not spam filtering, this is a mistake lots of people make.  Strong indicators of spam (images, links, etc.) are oftentimes also strong indicators of quality (well cited posts with diagrams, etc.).  Trying to argue about quality checks from a spam basis is inherently faulty, in short.  Resist the urge to Bayes everything, we actually invested non-trivial time in that and found it to be very very lacking.

Comment: @Jon - existing corpus of Stack Overflow questions, sorted into good and bad by hand naturally.  Was a community grant project iirc.

Comment: @Jon - there's a lot surprising about how our quality checks pan out; conventional wisdom doesn't apply most of the time.  I was a huge skeptic personally, but when you start looking into the data it becomes apparent that they do really work quite well.  There's also just a lot of ignorance in arguments about it, frankly.  People harping on all the "necessary uses of Problem" when problem is legitimately [used in less than 1/200 attempts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter) and so on.

Comment: @Jon - no, < 1/200; one post was a legit use of "problem" but the question itself was off topic (as admitted by the user, who self deleted it).  3 posts were made worse by the filter (that is, people hacked around it), but the uses of problem/help/etc. were still incorrect.  I am also completely unsympathetic to an argument that we shouldn't do the right thing because it isn't popular; we do lots of unpopular things (closing questions, down votes, user asking bans, etc.), they work really well too so we're going to keep doing them.

Comment: @Jon I find calling it a pet peeve is disingenuous in the extreme.  We found these indicators by looking at a set of known low quality posts and found these few words were strong indicators, we didn't start from "I hate it when X is used in titles".

Comment: Here, have a link: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/customerservice.html  (The point is it _appears_ to be arbitrary or a pet peeve.  I'll delete my comments, which just wasted all of our time.)

Comment: All I can say is that the number of questions with "problem" replaced by "issue" has *significantly* increased on Super User. Is that really what you want?

Comment: only .2%... of 4 million questions. you're right, is not worth a fix for *8,000* questions, or roughly *5 per day* for the entire existence of SO. seriously? i don't even care about this request, but that's just bad logic.

Comment: This rule is a real nuisance.

Comment: Those pesky high-rep users have extra privileges. Same rules should apply to everyone. I won't even talk about editing or close votes, but about something very basic: if 0-rep can't downvote - nobody should be allowed to. No exceptions.