# Editing a question title with the term "problem"

Tags: bug, title, edits, question-restrictions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the word “problem” in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)
>   [Let users with sufficient reputation use “problem” in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles)

I found this question: [How do I resolve the "Crypt Kicker" exercise proposed in "Programming Challenges (The Programming Contest Training Manual)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175356/crypt-kicker-problem-programming-challeneges)

And as you can see, the word "Challenges" is misspelled.

I tried editing the title, but it doesn't allow me, telling me that:
**"please do not use these words in titles: 'Problem'"**

The *problem* with this is that the term "Problem" is really a part of the question:
**"Crypt Kicker Problem" (Programming Challenges)**

How to overcome this?

Comment: Please oh please Jeff, let us use "Problem" in question titles at least with some minimum amount of reputation.

Comment: What do you know -  "Crypt Kicker Pröblem" would work. Maybe we need to use that as a workaround? Or some Unicode `o` - but that destroys searchability

Comment: My related feature request: [Let users with sufficient reputation use “problem” in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles)

Comment: Also, my favorite workaround: Use the Greek capital Rho: Ρ – it breaks searches, but at least you get a decent readable title. That's what happens when they include "features" like this.

Comment: "Crypt Kicker Challenge" would work and get the point across, but I'll offer that as an aside, as I don't think it's an argument for having the filter in place.

Comment: If it's not allowed, how did it get there in the first place?  I call bug.

Comment: @donroby The filter has been applied just recently. This means that questions with "problem" in the title can exist, but new ones can not be added.

Comment: Why the downvote? what's the *problem*? :)

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't say you were removing "(programming challenges)", thus making your effort to edit the title pointless.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ I didn't say because I wasn't. Where have you read that? I just wanted to correct "Challeneges" that's all.

Comment: @jackJoe: My (joke-y) point was that the whole *(programming challenges)* meta tag should have been removed from the title.  Yes, its outside the scope of your question, but tags that aren't organic to the title should be purged with as much violence and hatred as possible.  They should be cored out with a red hot poker, and doused in vinegar afterwards.

Comment: I just ran into this problem with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922815/how-to-create-fxcop-problemitem-object-with-correct-line-number-in-source  Unfortunately, the filter even prevents it in the middle/end of a class name: Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Problem

Comment: See also [Using the word "problem" in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)

Comment: The same thing happens with the word "question" in titles. >:(

Comment: Bump for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771/what-is-the-biggest-problemm-with-software-development). Trying to edit and correct spelling of "problemm"

Comment: Same here, I have tried to edit the title of the question [Transportation probelm with available source is more than destination](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11868145/341970) where the word problem is completely justfied. Another example is the travelling salesman problem (TSP). Ah, sorry, probelm, so that I can write it into the title...

Answer (score 4):

I got this same *problem* problem just now when attempting to fix the typo in ["Josephus-problm" using list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444979/josephus-problm-using-list-in-python). Or perhaps this isn't a typo but a workaround.

This issue seems to have been discussed many times (e.g. [Why can't we use the word "problem" in titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)), and the majority (including SO staff) seem to believe that the word filter (at least for *problem*) should be deactivated. I wonder why it isn't done.

Comment: I know, but in this case (this question) the *problem* is that the term "problem" is already present, and if I try to edit anything else it won'l let me until I change the term "problem" from the title, that's a loop.

Comment: @jackJoe You are right my problem isn't actually the same as yours. Still, the whole word filtering isn't a good idea. I just wanted to add another case.

Answer (score 2):

Where the word "Problem" [already exists in a question title](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6745146/revisions), we should be able to retain it when editing other parts of the question.

Comment: This won't help when someone wants to ask a brand-new question about the Travelling Salesman Problem.

Comment: what about TSP or just Pro-blem? is the parser smart enough to ignore hyphens?

Comment: @prusswan That's not the point.  We shouldn't have to work around the pr0blem.

Comment: @PopularDemand. Yes, getting rid of the filter altogether would be even better, but that appears to be a lost cause.

Comment: I like pr0blem actually, if only SO isn't such a serious place

Comment: "Such a serious place," really? I don't think very many people are Googling for "The Halting Pr0blem" every day, @prusswan. (Okay, writing that made me curious. The first two [results for "Halting Pr0blem"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=strict&sa=X&ei=kvv9Ts64L-Xo0QHhucTHDw&ved=0CBsQvgUoAA&q=Halting+Pr0blem&nfpr=1&biw=1050&bih=1596) are MSO posts about this very issue. They're followed by... a rap battle transcript and a low-quality OCR?)

Comment: I interpreted that as a 'leet' joke, looks like I was mistaken. Seriously though I would expect the search engine to be robust enough to handle one-character-off typos, making this less of an issue