# Mobile site doesn't fade downvoted answers

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, mobile-web

On my mobile (Android Browser 2.3.4), heavily downvoted answers like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111000/168428) are not faded out as they are in a full-fledged browser.  I cannot speak for other mobile browsers, as this is the only one I have to test on.

Is this "by design", or an oversight (bug)?  I don't see a reason for it *not* to be the same on the mobile site, but I could be missing something.

Comment: Repro in iPhone.

Comment: @ShawnChin Thanks!  I was hoping someone would jump in and check that =)

Comment: Repro on Android 2.2

Comment: Norepro on iPad running desktop. One sec while I check mobile

Comment: Repro on iPad forced-mobile

Comment: You could check out the CSS by force-mobiling on Chrome and using the dev tools(I'd do it myself, but comp off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the post body text #888 for heavily downvoted answers. This will be out in the next build (`2230` here and `1596` on the network)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `div` containing the answer has `answer-summary answer downvoted-answer` on the mobile site already, all it requires is one line of CSS:

`.downvoted-answer td.votecell, .downvoted-answer div.post-text{color:#888888}`

Should do the trick. (I think)

Then again, the mobile site is supposed to have limited functionality anyway<sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

And how useful is this feature, really? All it does is make downvoted answers hard to read--and you can glean quite a bit of information from downvoted answers. Pretty useless :/

So this is probably bydesign, and will probably be declined if you make it into a featurereq.

Comment: If it is, indeed, as simple as you say, I don't see why it should be declined.  I could understand it being bydesign (since it's mobile, and mobile is not exactly like the full site), but it *is* inconsistent.  Thanks for looking into the stylsheet =)

Comment: This is dumb.  This is stupid.

Comment: @jadarnel27: ?? O_0

Comment: Oh, hey Manish.  What's up?

Comment: @jadarnel27: Vacashun!!