# Alert problematic titles prior to editing

Tags: feature-request, edits

It happened in the meantime quite often to me: I am editing a minor issue and upon saving, I am informed that SO refuses the edit because I should also edit the title. So my time is lost, if I do not find an appropriate replacement. This is the moment where I think: Oh, once again, my time is absorbed by a black hole.

One effect is that there is a lot of creativity to write the word problem: pro blem, probIem, prob|em, problèm.

Suggestion: Alert the editing person at the time when the edit is **started**. Currently, an edit is meekly permitted, and only upon saving the user is informed to perform this other task.

I have encountered this problem several times in the past, and it is really frustrating, in particular when retagging. Also, what should one do with a title like [NP-complete knapsack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6253519/772868)

Comment: Perhaps a better solution to this "issue" would be to allow editors to simply [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108815/1438) things as they see fit.  The title filter _might_ make sense for newly asked questions, but the argument breaks down for questions that have been reviewed by a human the system trusts to make edits.

Comment: @JonEricson: SE won't even give mods the power to make the necessary corrections, so I really doubt they will give this ability to editors.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: it is no probIem (with a capital i not an L...)

Answer (score 1):

Editing the title is not a required part of the editing process, unless a word in the title was blacklisted after the post was made.

"Problem" is a blacklisted word; substitute "issue" instead.

Comment: Not in this case, though. "NP-complete problem" is a technical term, "NP-complete issue" is - what?

Comment: Ah. So if problem is bad, how is issue any better? You'd have to block this as well, it adds no value either (but then again, god forbid someone might ask about issue tracking)

Comment: @slhck: You'd have to ask SE about that.  I believe SE chose the words based on their correlation to very low quality posts, and apparently use of the word "problem" has a very strong correlation, while "issue" does not.

Comment: For completeness: There is no halting issue, nor a NP-complete issue. SO does not do a favor to poor CS students.