# Title Rename Prevention from Questio to Question

Tags: discussion

There is a question about [NLP and Question answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966285/nlp-questio-answering-retrieving-information-from-db) in stackoverflow. Question's title is "NLP/Questio Answering - Retrieving information from DB". When I try to fix NLP/Questio to NLP/Question. Stack overflow bugs me about good title practices.

I think apparent spelling mistake (Questio ) is worse than a real word of Question in Title. Shouldn't be a way to fix this title? Our edits go from peer review? Therefore Why this rename is not allowed?

Comment: Closely related: [Why can't we use the word "problem" in titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107989), [Let users with sufficient reputation use "problem" in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108815), [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944)

Comment: @Atilla - It's supposed to stop you from using "I have a Question" as the subject. As you see, it doesn't work that well.