# Forced to edit the title in a migrated question

Tags: discussion, edits, migration, title, quality-filter

I recently edited a Stack Overflow question that was migrated from stats.stackexchange.com. My intention was to add new tags; however, I could not submit the edit with the original question title since the title contained the word "problem" (as a part of "Knapsack problem").

I ended up changing the title, but it felt unfair to the OP. Are there guidelines for this kind of situation?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did the right thing by changing the title.

Quality filters in Stack Overflow are strict for a reason, to prevent as much low quality content as possible in advance, before it's even posted.

Title containing the word "problem" is usually a low quality title that does not describe the actual problem, e.g. "Halp! I got a problem!!", so by blocking it, SO deters many low quality questions, and if the person asking really wants, they can make the title better and post their question.

The edge cases where the word "problem" is legit in titles are rare, and don't justify removing the block in my opinion.

Worth to mention here [Let users with sufficient reputation use "problem" in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles) that was declined years ago, against many people's will.