# How do I STOP the search bar changing size when entering text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, usability

I find it very distracting the way the search bar changes size when I start typing in the search box. On my monitor my input cursor is at around pixel X of around 1200 when I start typing but then the input cursor suddenly jumps to around pixel X 900 as it expands. It's an 'uncomfortable' feeling, on a site that is otherwise super comfy, as I have to adjust my eye focus point.

I'm sure some people love it but I'd rather have a button that I can click to expand the field when I want it resized rather than it happen automatically.

Comment: Which site are you on?  The search box doesn't expand for me anymore on Stack Overflow or here, in either IE or Firefox.

Comment: I still see it expand when I start typing in Firefox.

Comment: Ah, start typing.  Never mind.  It's the beloved auto-expanding supercollider searchbox.  It will die when you pry it out of the developers' cold, dead hands.

Comment: @snowdude, [you're not alone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101387/164403).

Comment: I'm normally working on FireFox but it happens on IE too.

Comment: You wait until you write a really long search request, then you'll be thanking this functionality because you can read/review before you submit the search

Comment: @DanielHanly `str.length()` is still there in JS. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eeek, the super-mega-expando search box is annoying, part 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101862/eeek-the-super-mega-expando-search-box-is-annoying-part-2)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with the new top bar.